# Why Ant add an equal character in properties file

Tags: encoding, ant, properties-file

I have a some given properties file like this :

```
firstvalue=1
secondvalue=hello
```

I use this Ant script to change a value :

```
    <propertyfile file="A.properties">
        <entry key="firstvalue" value="2" />
    </propertyfile>
```

After executing the script, the properties file is now :

```
#Wed, 20 May 2015 11:42:46 +0200
=
firstvalue=2
secondvalue=hello
```

I understand why the Ant task add a comment with the date, but why Ant also add this symbol equal at the second line ?

I supposed that it is due to the encoding file because I can't reproduce the problem with all my properties file but only with some files that someone else manually made. Is there a way to avoid this behavior or fix the encoding before use the file in Ant ?

EDIT : 
Here is my property file see before the script whith an online hexdump tool :
file name: A.properties
mime type:

```
0000-0010:  ef bb bf 0d-0a 66 69 72-73 74 76 61-6c 75 65 3d  .....fir stvalue=
0000-0020:  31 0d 0a 73-65 63 6f 6e-64 76 61 6c-75 65 3d 68  1..secon dvalue=h
0000-0024:  65 6c 6c 6f  

                                ello
```

And the same file after :

```
file name: A.properties
mime type: 

0000-0010:  23 54 68 75-2c 20 32 31-20 4d 61 79-20 32 30 31  #Thu,.21 .May.201
0000-0020:  35 20 31 35-3a 32 31 3a-31 32 20 2b-30 32 30 30  5.15:21: 12.+0200
0000-0030:  0d 0a ef bb-bf 3d 0d 0a-66 69 72 73-74 76 61 6c  .....=.. firstval
0000-0040:  75 65 3d 32-0d 0a 73 65-63 6f 6e 64-76 61 6c 75  ue=2..se condvalu
0000-0049:  65 3d 68 65-6c 6c 6f 0d-0a                       e=hello. .
```

Comment: I would run xxd (or find some online hexdump tool).  Otherwise, it's going to be difficult for people to guess at the problem.

Comment: I had the Hex dump of my file before and after executing the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the UTF-8-encoded byte-order-mark at the front of the file (ef bb ff).  Properties files are always encoded in ISO8859-1, not UTF-8, so the files are not valid properties files.  I strongly recommend fixing the properties files (and make the other person switch to an editor that doesn't reintroduce the problem), but if you need a short-term workaround, you could first remove the BOM:

```
<copy file="A.properties" encoding="UTF-8" tofile="A.properties.tmp">
  <filterchain>
    <deletecharacters chars="&#xfeff;"/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
<move file="A.properties.tmp" tofile="A.properties"/>

<propertyfile file="A.properties">
  <entry key="firstvalue" value="2" />
</propertyfile>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as I want. As you said, I will fix all the properties files and say to the other person to use an editor which doesn't make any problem.